# why Ajax call's are slower with wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, performance

I am working on my localhost (xampp) and I made an API call on Wordpress with ajax,
This API allows me to search for users (/users?keywords=) or get one directly with its ID (/users/{id}).
I create a searchbar which trigger an Ajax call to 'admin-ajax.php' linked to a function I made to get the API result in the functions.php.
Everything is working but the ajax call is too slow.
I compare it with a none Wordpress project (simple php and js script) who did the same :

|  | API call duration | total duration (API + ajax) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| With Wordpress Ajax | 0.35 s | 3.2s |
| With Wordpress Rest API | 0.35 s | 2.9s |
| Without Wordpress | 0.35 s | 0.9s |

Note: I enter the same input in the search bar to get this result above.

Is it normal to get that much difference with Wordpress? I probably did something wrong, can you tell me what are the possible causes of this? Let me know if I need to clarify anything or add some details.

Response to @amarinediary:

Initially, I had a template called "Matching" that contained the search bar. When the search bar form was submitted, a JS function parsed the form data and called the $.ajax function. The url used was "admin_url(admin-ajax.php)" and the "action" parameter allowed a function, in functions.php, to validate a nonce and make the call to the API.
=> The result was correct but slow.

Now, I tryed the rest API,
When the searchbar form is submitted, the $.ajax() url is "get_rest_url(null, 'route')". It then works the same way as initially except that the nonce is no longer validated by "wp_verify-nonce".
=> The result is good and a little faster (see table)

So, I have many questions.
First, did I made a mistake on my try with rest API?
If no, is the nonce checker still mandatory with rest API ?
If so, Why the wp_verify_nonce does not work anymore with the REST API ?
And finnaly, which one is more optimized ?

New Questioning :

The web application I'm trying to develop is entirely based on an external API. I need to make dynamic GET requests (such as the search bar) and display the result, I need to send forms with POST requests, my application is just an interface for this API. I don't need wordpress articles and I can't create pages displaying the results of my API requests via the admin interface. So I have to create many templates to get the pages I want.

So I come to this question: is Wordpress really relevant in my case since I don't use its main features?
What do you thnik about it ?

I have the feeling that the answer is no and that I should go for another solution like Angular, react, vueJS or a framework like Laravel or Symfony.

Comment: Wordpress is a CMS: whenever you request a page, it starts a loading sequence that involves an awful lot of PHP files and SQL queries. https://medium.com/@dendeffe/wordpress-loading-sequence-a-guided-tour-e077c7dbd119 If you compare that to a simple PHP page, of course WP is slower.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer,
more than 3 seconds of waiting for each search, it is a lot, how can I reduce this search time?

Comment: Instead of an ajax call you can pass through the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/). Which should be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @amarinediary, I tried what you advised, I edited the post to show you what I did, can you check it? I also put a question

Comment: Let's see the generated SQL.

Answer (score 0):

> A nonce is a "number used once" to help protect URLs and forms from certain types of misuse, malicious or otherwise.

But even tho, Nonces are NOT a security measure. It's just a request filter. Nonces are passed to javascript through a `<script>` tag, via a simple javascript comment when localizing data. You can actually see it in your source code.

```js
/* <![CDATA[ */
var data = {
    "_ajax_url":"https:\/\/...\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php",
    "_ajax_nonce":"5694443d46"
};
/* ]]> */
```

> Nonces should never be relied on for authentication, authorization, or access control. Protect your functions using current_user_can(), and always assume nonces can be compromised.

- @See https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces

By default the REST API is Open to all.

> [...] You may use a filter to require that API consumers be authenticated, which effectively prevents anonymous external access. See below for more information.

Implying that none of the published data is initially secure (funny story, a lot of WordPress site using a paywall don't have a restricted REST API access).

WordPress is build with technologies on top of each others. Ajax calls came first, the API came later. Both have a different goal.

Usually response time doesn't depends on the backend used but more on how the request is implemented. The more specific and restricted a request is, the more "optimized" it will be. It's difficult to say or give example in your case as I don't understand what '/users?keywords=' should return. But if you're building an endpoint to retrieve specific data, there is probably a way more easier answer using the `WP_Query`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, when I send '/users?keywords=john' to the API, it returns with a list of users whose first or last name contains the keywords, here 'john'. /users/{id}' returns the unique user concerned by the ID.

Comment: I will check the WP_query

Comment: I didn't specify it but the API I need to call is external.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to make my api calls with WP_query. The solution I found to use WP_query is to create custom posts in which I initially store the users obtained via the api and then to access to them with the WP_query. This is not what I want. There may be another way, but I haven't found it.

Comment: I add a part at the end of my post